# Windows Phone 7 without db support

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm disappointed in seeing that no DB support has been added to the new MS mobile platform ... what do they think about great and full Sqlite integration in iPhone and/or Android??

I think that in a mobile app a local db is a good good thing.

Comment: Is there a real question here?  I'm certainly not seeing it.

Comment: wow....very useful comment; i was only asking what developers think about a great (for me) lack in a new software platform. Did you need a question mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that on Windows Phone 7 you can still use SQLite.NET(http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), so this not such a big problem.